# indent of custom float

Tags: floats, captions, indentation

In my preamble I defined a custom float to use it for my equations like this

```
\newfloat{formula}{ht}{frm}
\floatname{formula}{Formel}
```

then I use it like this

```
\begin{formula}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
D(x,y,\sigma) & = & (G(x,y,k\sigma) - G(x,y,\sigma)) * I(x,y) \\
              & = & L(x,y,k\sigma) - L(x,y,\sigma)
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\caption[\glsentrydesc{DOG}]{\glsentrydesc{DOG} $D$ zweier benachbarter Bilder mit Weichzeichnungsfaktor $k$}
\end{formula}
```

which displays like that

[image: custom float with long caption]

The caption is pretty long and there is a line break in it. How can I achive that "faktor k" appears right under "Difference" instead of "Formel 2" ?

I'm asking because regular captions for a figure show up differently. I want the above example to show up like that

[image: long caption in figure block]

Here is a minimal document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newfloat{formula}{ht}{frm}
\floatname{formula}{Formel}

\newacronym{DOG}{DoG}{Difference of Gaussian}

\begin{document}

\begin{formula}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
D(x,y,\sigma) & = & (G(x,y,k\sigma) - G(x,y,\sigma)) * I(x,y) \\
             & = & L(x,y,k\sigma) - L(x,y,\sigma)
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\caption[\glsentrydesc{DOG}]{\glsentrydesc{DOG} $D$ zweier benachbarter Bilder mit Weichzeichnungsfaktor $k$}
\end{formula}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When using a KOMA-Script document class I would personally drop usage of the float package and use `\DeclareNewTOC` (offered by KOMA-Script) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package to define the new float produces the desire formatting for the caption:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{floatrow} 

\newfloat{formula}{ht}{frm} 
\floatname{formula}{Formel} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{formula} 
\begin{equation} 
a=b
\end{equation} 
\caption{$D$ zweier benachbarter Bilder mit Weichzeichnungsfaktor $k$ and some more text} 
\end{formula} 

\end{document}
```

[image]